# Google Sheets - How to transform table data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a data with and ID and numeric value, organized by date in columns, like this

| ClusterID | Pos. 2024-01-01 | Pos. 2024-01-02 | ..... | Pos. 2024-03-24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100015 | 1053 | 1027 | ..... | 327 |
| 230022 |  | 9002 | ..... | 101 |
| ...... |  |  | ..... |  |
| 320024 | 74 | 98 | ..... | 2 |

And I would like to have this data in rows:

| ClusterID | Position | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100015 | 1053 | 2024-01-01 |
| 100015 | 1027 | 2024-01-02 |
| 100015 | .... | .... |
| 100015 | 327 | 2024-03-24 |
| 100022 |  | 2024-01-01 |
| 100022 | 9002 | 2024-01-02 |
| 100022 | .... | .... |
| 100022 | 101 | 2024-03-24 |
| 100024 | 74 | 2024-01-01 |
| 100024 | 98 | 2024-01-02 |
| 100024 | .... | .... |
| 100024 | 2 | 2024-03-24 |

I tried transpose() and query but stuck with big amount of columns in my sample.

Here is the link with some data in GS: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/186hcvRHUAN3VRPwMO5jaZbF8ozft-waxTGpCCh-uPFQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,tocol(,1), reduce(Σ,Sheet1!B2:index(Sheet1!CG:CG,match(,0/(Sheet1!A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(if(iserror(a&""),Σ,a),
                  if(len(c),hstack(index(Sheet1!A:A,row(c)),c,mid(index(Sheet1!1:1,column(c)),6,10)),Σ)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I don't understand - how, but gave me some time ))

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
=arrayformula(let(
maxrow,counta(Sheet1!A2:A),
maxcol,counta(Sheet1!B1:1),
clusterID,offset(Sheet1!A2,,,maxrow),
date,regexextract(offset(Sheet1!B1,,,,maxcol),"Plc. (.+)"),
position,offset(Sheet1!B2,,,maxrow,maxcol),
split(tocol(if(len(position),clusterID&"|"&position&"|"&date,),1),"|")))
```

We are defining the maximum dimensions of your *position* matrix then using these values to define three variables corresponding to *clusterID*, *position* & *date* (using regex to extract the date). We then collect all the values together in a string for each non-empty position using a 2D `if`, flatten it to a single column using `tocol` and then split the separate values back out into separate columns using `split`.

Comment: Also works perfectly for my data, big thanks, you've helped me a lot :-)